# Can a Google Apps Script Web App using UiService be tracked with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps-script

Is there any possibility to to insert a working Google Analytics tracker into a web app using UiApp as user interface?

This would provide the app owner with in depth usage statistics.

The only possible alternative i can think of, storing every access to the web app including user's Id in the ScriptDb, is problematic from the data privacy point and doesn't provide the essential informations about the user like location, language or device.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's totally doable and I have an internal library for this. The concept is you Urlfetch a gif from the google analytics server and pass data via the querystring. Here's working code and a test. Google Analytics docs references are inline :

Edit:  I have packaged the below as a Library called GASAnalytics and added the project key "MvzvykyEXRZJoG1Gjj2h1JnHAGDwXQ1CH" to the More Google Apps Script Libraries list here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhDqyd_bUCmvdGxjNUpGZkFKcmxsekE3VHNWMEh4amc#gid=0

```
/**
* hits Google Analytics with a "path" you want to track as a pageview 
* e.g. track("UA-ABC123-4", "/track/my/event")
*/
function track(propertyId, path) {
  //ref https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gifParameters
  //https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

   var utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";

    // Construct the gif hit url.
    var utmUrl = utmGifLocation + "?" +
    "utmwv=4.4sa" +
    //"&utmcn=1"+ //added - extra - not required
    "&utmn=" +  (new Date().getTime())+ //unique - cache buster
    "&utmhn=" + 'example.com' +
    "&utmr=" + '-' +
    "&utmp=" + encodeURIComponent(path) + 
    "&utmac=" + propertyId +
    "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" +
    "&utmvid=" + Math.random() +
    "&utmip=" + '-';


  Logger.log("Fetching " + utmUrl);
  var test = UrlFetchApp.fetch(utmUrl);
  return;
}

function testTrack() {
  // confirm in GA > Realtime (immediate) or Standard Reports > Content > Content drilldown (after 2 hours)
  track("UA-heyuseyourown:/!", "/track1/my1/test1"); 
}
```

Let us know how you go.

Comment: The solution you propose doesn't the same as Google Analytics Tracker code. Here are the remaining problems:

Comment: The visitor logged is always the GAS Server - the information about location, language or device of the actual user is lost. The script will request the user to authorize the URLfetch on his behalf.

Comment: Yes it's different because you can't make the code run in the browser. Code is always invoked serverside and client browser data and cookies are not exposed past the server. For example, you can't get lang or useragent from the browser nor referer or ip. I don't think HtmlService changes that. For location, my GA reporting shows the hit as coming from Australia > Sydney so the script.google.com servers are at least able to do some smart edge caching with locations (but maybe not yours). Regarding auth, you can't bypass GAS security controls so the effective user must authorize it (once).